# Can you see the pattern?

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

Can you solve this and explain the pattern?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Is this puzzle your own creation?

Comment: @xyldke It was presented to me in an online aptitude training test, it's kind of driving me crazy right now, I can't see the pattern. Sorry, I don't remember which website, showed up in a Google image search. You can do a reverse image search if you want to find the source

Comment: Looks like it's from here: https://expertassignmenthelp.com/what-are-the-different-classroom-assessment-techniques-used-in-your-university-4/